# Angular Full Stack Example on github

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I am trying to understand the example of Angular full stack project but I am not able to do so! 
The project is here:

https://github.com/DavideViolante/Angular-Full-Stack

in the package.json, you can find a "dev" script to test locally the app. the command is the following:

```
concurrently \"mongod\" \"ng serve -pc proxy.conf.json --open\" \"tsc -w -p server\" \"nodemon dist/server/app.js\"
```

I don't understand why ng serve is called and app.js also. I mean ng serve create a static file server and there is also a static file server with Express. So launching that starts two servers. What's the point?

Comment: ng serve = front end, nodemon app.js = backend/api

Answer (score 2):

Here is a breakdown of all command

concurrently  -- runs all command simultaneoulsy

\"mongod\"    -- To Start MongoDB server

\"ng serve -pc proxy.conf.json --open\"  -- To serve angular stuff

\"tsc -w -p server\"   -- run the compiler in watch mode and compile project

\"nodemon dist/server/app.js\"  -- to run your server side project

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this project but the app.js normally is for the back-end and the ng serve is for serving an angular project in your development environment.

I hope this help.